# Pandas Dataframe: Multiplying Two Columns

Tags: python, pandas, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to multiply two columns (ActualSalary * FTE) within the dataframe (OPR) to create a new column (FTESalary), but somehow it has stopped at row 21357, I don't understand what went wrong or how to fix it. The two columns came from importing a csv file using the line: `OPR = pd.read_csv('OPR.csv', encoding='latin1')`

```
[In] OPR
[out]
ActualSalary    FTE
44600           1
58,000.00       1
70,000.00       1
17550           1
34693           1
15674           0.4

[In] OPR["FTESalary"] = OPR["ActualSalary"].str.replace(",", "").astype("float")*OPR["FTE"]
[In] OPR
[out]
ActualSalary    FTE FTESalary
44600           1   44600
58,000.00       1   58000
70,000.00       1   70000
17550           1   NaN
34693           1   NaN
15674           0.4 NaN
```

I am not expecting any NULL values as an output at all, I am really struggling with this. I would really appreciate the help.
Many thanks in advance! (I am new to both coding and here, please let me know via message if I have made mistakes or can improve the way I post questions here)

Sharing the data @oppresiveslayer

```
[In] OPR[0:6].to_dict()
[out]
{'ActualSalary': {0: '44600',
1: '58,000.00',
2: '70,000.00',
3: '39,780.00',
4: '0.00',
5: '78,850.00'},
 'FTE': {0: 1.0, 1: 1.0, 2: 1.0, 3: 1.0, 4: 1.0, 5: 1.0}}
```

For more information on the two columns @charlesreid1

```
[in] OPR['ActualSalary'].astype
[out]
Name: ActualSalary, Length: 21567, dtype: object>

[in] OPR['FTE'].astype
[out]
Name: FTE, Length: 21567, dtype: float64>
```

The version I am using: 
python: 3.7.3, pandas: 0.25.1 on jupyter Notebook 6.0.0

Comment: Possibly a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14059094/i-want-to-multiply-two-columns-in-a-pandas-dataframe-and-add-the-result-into-a-n

Comment: It is a good read for me, a lot to learn, but unfortunately not quite the same issue I am experiencing here. Thanks though @charlesreid1

Comment: By _construct_ the dataframes, are you referring to how I have those data in the first place? I have loaded it from a csv file. The ActualSalary is dtype: object, whereas FTE is dtype: float64. I will amend my question to include this now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that your `ActualSalary` column is a mix of strings and integers.  That is the only way I've been able to recreate your error:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'ActualSalary': ['44600', '58,000.00', '70,000.00', 17550, 34693, 15674],
     'FTE': [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0.4]})

>>> df['ActualSalary'].str.replace(',', '').astype(float) * df['FTE']
0    44600.0
1    58000.0
2    70000.0
3        NaN
4        NaN
5        NaN
dtype: float64
```

The issue arises when you try to remove the commas:

```
>>> df['ActualSalary'].str.replace(',', '')
0       44600
1    58000.00
2    70000.00
3         NaN
4         NaN
5         NaN
Name: ActualSalary, dtype: object
```

First convert them to strings, before converting back to floats.

```
fte_salary = (
    df['ActualSalary'].astype(str).str.replace(',', '')  # Remove commas in string, e.g. '55,000.00' -> '55000.00'
    .astype(float)  # Convert string column to floats.
    .mul(df['FTE'])  # Multiply by new salary column by Full-Time-Equivalent (FTE) column.
)
>>> df.assign(FTESalary=fte_salary)  # Assign new column to dataframe.
      ActualSalary  FTE  FTESalary
    0        44600  1.0    44600.0
    1    58,000.00  1.0    58000.0
    2    70,000.00  1.0    70000.0
    3        17550  1.0    17550.0
    4        34693  1.0    34693.0
    5        15674  0.4     6269.6
```

Comment: I have previously used the .mul method as well but yielded the same problem I am facing, unfortunately.

Comment: @SyLviA I cannot replicate your error. What version of python and pandas are you using?

Comment: python: 3.7.3, pandas: 0.25.1
I am using the jupyter Notebook 6.0.0 @Alexander

Comment: I think the issue is that the `ActualSalary` column is initially a mix of integers and strings. Try first to cast it to strings and then continue as above, ie. `df['ActualSalary'].astype(str).str.replace(',', '').astype(float).mul(df['FTE'])`

Comment: Thank you so much @Alexander, that fixed the issue!! The whole having to cast it to strings and then continue with my original code! I am so happy, however I don't understand why I have to cast it to string first if it's a mixture? Thank you once again!

Comment: Because calling `str.replace()` on an integer gives you a null so effectively you are converting `None` to `float` and multiplying `None` and FTE hence the `NaN`. You convert them all to string so even the integers are strings so calling `str.replace()` gives the string with desired character replacements.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
OTR['FTESalary'] = OTR.apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x['ActualSalary'].replace(",", ""), errors='coerce') * x['FTE'], axis=1)
```

output

```
  ActualSalary  FTE  FTESalary
0        44600  1.0    44600.0
1    58,000.00  1.0    58000.0
2    70,000.00  1.0    70000.0
3        17550  1.0    17550.0
4        34693  1.0    34693.0
5        15674  0.4     6269.6
```

ok, i think you need to do this:

```
OTR['FTESalary'] = OTR.reset_index().apply(lambda x: pd.to_numeric(x['ActualSalary'].replace(",", ""), errors='coerce') * x['FTE'], axis=1).to_numpy().tolist()
```

Comment: I have tried applying your code to mine but have this error below (I am still early stage of learning the meaning of these messages...)

`AttributeError: ("'int' object has no attribute 'replace'", 'occurred at index 20480')`

Comment: @sylvia, what is the output of pd.__version__   i think i need to install you version to see the error message. I don't mind doing so, so i can get  a working version

Comment: it is '0.25.1' (thanks for teaching me how to check the version) @oppressionslayer

Comment: @SyLviA Ok, i added an update, can you try that. I got the same error as you, so i think i fixed it. IT's actually not a bug, but because we need to reset_index since you have an index set already.

Comment: I still have the same error: `AttributeError: ("'int' object has no attribute 'replace'", 'occurred at index 20480')`
Is this because I don't know how to 'clean' the raw csv file? @oppressionslayer

Comment: I get that error like that if i remove reset_index: KeyError: ('ActualSalary', 'occurred at index 44600').  Would you be able to give us your data, df[0:6].to_dict()  ?

Comment: `(      ActualSalary  FTE
 0            44600  1.0
 1        58,000.00  1.0
 2        70,000.00  1.0
 3        39,780.00  1.0
 4             0.00  1.0
 ...            ...  ...
 21562        70000  1.0
 21563        55000  1.0
 21564        59872  1.0
 21565        93000  1.0
 21566        52000  1.0
 
 [21567 rows x 2 columns],
 {'ActualSalary': {0: '44600',
   1: '58,000.00',
   2: '70,000.00',
   3: '39,780.00',
   4: '0.00',
   5: '78,850.00'},
  'FTE': {0: 1.0, 1: 1.0, 2: 1.0, 3: 1.0, 4: 1.0, 5: 1.0}})` @oppressionslayer  I've removed other columns of original dataframe

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it in a couple steps, but with list comprehension which might be less readable for a beginner. It makes an intermediate column, which does the float conversion, since your ActualSalary column is full of strings at the start.

```
OPR["X"] = [float(x.replace(",","")) for x in OPR["ActualSalary"]]
OPR["FTESalary"] = OPR["X"]*OPR["FTE"]
```

Comment: I have used your code above and unfortunately I am still having the same issue.