# Create two new fields at once in pandas dataframe based off of calculations of other fields

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I am iterating over a series of csv files as dataframes, eventually writing them all out to a common excel workbook.

In one of the many files, there are decimal GPS values (latitude, longitude) split into two columns (`df[4]` and `df[5]`) that I'm converting to degrees-minutes-seconds.  That method returns a tuple that I'm attempting to park in two new fields called `dmslat` and `dmslon` in the same row of the original dataframe:

```
def convert_dd_to_dms(lat, lon):
    # does the math here
    return dmslat, dmslon

csv_dir = askdirectory()  # tkinter directory picker
os.chdir(csv_dir)
for f in glob.iglob("*.csv"):
    (csv_path, csv_name) = os.path.split(f)
    (csv_prefix, csv_ext) = os.path.splitext(csv_name)
    if csv_prefix[-3:] == "loc":
        df = pd.read_csv(f)
        df['dmslat'] = None
        df['dmslon'] = None
        for i, row in df.iterrows():
            fixed_coords = convert_dd_to_dms(row[4], row[5])
            row['dmslat'] = fixed_coords[0]
            row['dmslon'] = fixed_coords[1]
        print(df)
# process the other files
```

So when I use a `print()` statement I can see the coords are properly calculated but they are not being committed to the `dmslat`/`dmslon` fields.

I have also tried assigning the new fields within the row iterator, but since I am at the row scale, it ends up overwriting the entire column with the new calculated value every time.

How can I get the results to (succinctly) populate the columns?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that df.iterrows() is resulting in a "copy" of each row, thus when you add/update the columns "dmslat" and "dmslon", you are modifying the copy, not the original dataframe.  This can be confirmed by printing "row" after your assignments.  You will see the row item was successfully updated, but the changes are not reflected in the original dataframe.

To modify the original dataframe, you can modify your code as such:

```
        for i, row in df.iterrows():
            fixed_coords = convert_dd_to_dms(row[4], row[5])
            df.loc[i, 'dmslat'] = fixed_coords[0]
            df.loc[i, 'dmslon'] = fixed_coords[1]
        print(df)
```

using `df.loc` guarantees the changes are made to the original dataframe.

Comment: I understand.  Null values are fine as I can easily ignore them when iterating over the new data to construct a geometry layer (shapefile, etc).  Thanks for the super fast response.

Comment: you may also be able to accomplish this without a loop.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14059094/i-want-to-multiply-two-columns-in-a-pandas-dataframe-and-add-the-result-into-a-n.

Answer (score 0):

I think you better use `apply` rather than `iterrows`.

Here's a solution that is based on `apply`. I replaced your location calculation with a function named 'foo' which does some arbitrary calculation from two fields 'a' and 'b' to new values for 'a' and 'b'.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"a": range(10), "b":range(10, 20)})
def foo(row):
    return (row["a"] + row["b"], row["a"] * row["b"])

new_df = df.apply(foo, axis=1).apply(pd.Series)
```

In the above code block, applying 'foo' returns a tuple for every row. Using `apply` again with `pd.Series` turns it into a data frame.

```
df[["a", "b"]] = new_df
df.head(3) 

    a   b
0   10  0
1   23  132
2   38  336
```